# не рисует canvas в приложении для android (fmx)

Tags: android, canvas, c++builder, radstudio, firemonkey

```
Canvas->BeginScene();

TPointF a(wt,0);
TPointF centr(wt,ht);
Image1->Canvas->DrawLine(a,centr,100);

Canvas->EndScene();
```

При компиляции под компьютер - нормально отображает нарисованое, а при компиляции под андроид - нету рисунка.
radstudio c++builder (fmx)

Answer (score 0):

На Андроид надо определить параметры кисти и тд перед рисованием, тк дефолтные определяются в Винде, но не в Андроиде, поэтому у вас рисование при неопределенных параметрах происходит как надо, просто невидимыми красками)